# multiple like clauses? SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Ive tried IN, multiple like clauses etc.

**The problem:**
List BOOKs published by Jove, Penguin, Plume and Scholastic.  Organize by title within publisher.

**The desc table**

SQL> desc book

```
 Name
 ------------------
 BOOK_CODE
 TITLE
 PUBLISHER_CODE
 TYPE
 PRICE
 PAPERBACK
```

**sql Ive tried**

```
SQL> select * from BOOK where Publisher_Code IN(JP,PE,PL,SS)
  2  group by Publisher_code, title;

SQL> select * from BOOK
  2  where PUBLISHER_CODE IN('%JP%', '%PE%','%PL%', '%SC%')
  3  group by title, Publisher_code;


SQL> select * from book
  2  where Publisher_code like '%JP%'
  3  OR where Publisher_code like '%PE%'
  4  OR where Publisher_code like '%PL%'
  5  OR where Publisher_code like '%SC%'
  6  group by Publisher_code
  7  order by title;
```

Comment: I don't think that `oracle` would allow this type of `GROUP BY` usage. Are you sure you're not working with MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear why you are using `group by`.  You want `order by`.  Your example queries have very basic SQL mistakes, such as repeating the `where` keyword within a query.  Here is a version that seems to do what you want:

```
select b.*
from book b
where b.Publisher_code like '%JP%' or
      b.Publisher_code like '%PE%' or
      b.Publisher_code like '%PL%' or
      b.Publisher_code like '%SC%'
order by b.Publisher_code, b.Title;
```

As a note:  presumably the publisher codes are constants, and you don't need to use `like` with a wildcard.

Comment: Thanks! I used group by to try to differentiate from the code, and title.

Comment: @BrianWilson . . . You use `group by` to aggregate the data into fewer rows.  Use `order by` to put things in a praticular order.